# Is Shiva gita same as Ishvara Gita?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, gita, shiva-gita

Is Shiva gita same as Ishvara Gita or are they different?

What is its relationship with Kurma purana?

Is Shiva gita an authoritative scripture/pramana for any shaivite sect (agamic or non-agamic sect)?

Answer (score 10):

No those texts are not the same. Shiva Gita is from the Padma Purana whereas the Ishwara Gita is found in the Kurma Purana.

[Here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/siva-gita.htm) is Shiva Gita:

> The Siva-Gita is a text of Vedantic Saivism that comes to us from the
>   latter portion (uttara kanda) of the Padma Purana. In many ways, it is
>   a text not unlike the Bhagavad-Gita, except the focus is fully on
>   Siva. In the Siva-Gita, the teacher is Lord Siva and the disciple is
>   Sri Rama, and the narrator is Suta.

And, [here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/kurmapurana-11.htm) is an abridged summary of the Ishwara Gita from the Kurma Purana.

Another link for Ishwara Gita is [Kamakoti.org (Essence of Kurma Purana)](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/kurmapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=15).

Comment: Umm... why is it then that [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishvara_Gita) calls them same?

Comment: Iswara and Shiva are synonymous may be that's why. But they are not the same as shown in the answer. @kesarlingHe-Him